# Sharepoint project crashes when deploying

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, master-pages

I got a lot of projects for Sharepoint which all work fine instead of one. This project can only deployed by one developer of our team, all other devs keep getting an exception when trying to deploy that solution (building that solution works). (Both via Project, RMB in VS)

The error message is:

```
Error   1   Error occurred in deployment step 'Retract Solution': 
A communication error has occurred while invoking commands in SharePoint host process:
The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, 
cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.
```

I enabled logging in VS, but did not find any interesting stuff. Starting in /safemode did not help either. I also deleted the suo-file and all bin, obj and pkg-folders before deploying.

Any idea what went wrong?

(I did see the "Deploying Sharepoint 2010 Webpart crashes Visual Studio" topic but that was something different)

Answer (score 0):

Do iisreset and redeploy the project again .Application pool might be stopped sometimes causes this kind of error.